# Apache Mod Rewrite keep get parameters

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Firstly I'm no expert with mod rewrite but I have a URL I need to redirect.

The original URL is `categories.asp?cat1=1&cat2=2&cat3=58&cat4=96`

I need that to redirect to `/store/browse/category/TRADITIONAL-BRIDGE-SINK-MIXER/product-details/1901-Traditional-Bridge-Sink-Mixer-NDSMC`

Obviously there will be a lot of these to do and I'm happy enough to write each rule in turn.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you want to keep the get parameters whilst rewriting the url internally? Take a look at the `QSA` flag.

Comment: Not keep the parameter in one sense but 
?cat1=1&cat2=2&cat3=58&cat4=96 will go to one page
while
?cat1=1&cat2=2&cat3=58&cat4=92 will go to another

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is much more to do and not only with mod_rewrite.

You first would need to achieve this:

- allow to store the URL parts somewhere in the database for each category and product (probably based on language)
- show the URL for the products by concatenating these URL parts for each category until the concrete product

  - let's say keyword for category that the product is linked to will be `TRADITIONAL-BRIDGE-SINK-MIXER`, keyword for that product will be `1901-Traditional-Bridge-Sink-Mixer-NDSMC`
  - then You can generate this URL: `/store/browse/category/TRADITIONAL-BRIDGE-SINK-MIXER/product-details/1901-Traditional-Bridge-Sink-Mixer-NDSMC`
- then in .htaccess You would have something like this:

```txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^store\/browse\/category\/(.*)\/product-details\/(.*)$ product.php?category_id=$1&product_id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

The same way for categories, lets say for a URL `/store/browse/category/SINK-MIXER/TRADITIONAL-BRIDGE-SINK-MIXER/1901-Traditional-Bridge-Sink-Mixer-NDSMC` You would have a rule like:

```txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^store\/browse\/category\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)$ categories.php?category1_id=$1&category2_id=$2&category3_id=$3 [QSA,L]
```

This is not a solution, this is just a point to start from...

Comment: I'd hoped it would be a fairly simple thing.
I dont store the details as these links come from an old site and all I'm trying to do is maintain the links.
I tried a 301 but it breaks when you use parameters.

Comment: If this is the case then I would create some entry script, use mod_rewrite to send any `/store/browse/category/*` URL to that entry script (lets say `old_url_redirect.php`) that will parse that old URL, get the needed data chunks, find the new URL and redirect user to that new URL...May God be with You!

Comment: Hmm I'd love to do that. Great idea.

Unfortunately I can't as the system uses 404 errors from the index page to redirect and build the whole site.